# Which is the preferred way to change field content before rendered?

Tags: entities, 8

I'm working on an existing Drupal 7 module in order to make it work with Drupal 8. And for a peculiar aspect of its operation I'm currently a bit lost.

Th problem is that I must be able to make some changes in content of *any* text field, *everywhere throughout all contents*, before they're rendered.

In Drupal 7 I solved it behaving as a formatter, which I "grafted" before any existing formatter.
You can look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29341518/3415269) (I didn't know Drupal Answers at this time) to see more precisely how it worked.

After reading a lot of Drupal 8 documentation (which is currently quite messy) I can't yet realize **which is the preferred way to achieve what I want**.
I noticed some candidates such as the `hook_entity_view_alter()`, but also services and/or plugins, but keep totally undecided.

So I look for some advices pointing me to the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hook_entity_view_alter()` is for altering the render array of an entity, that is coming out of a view mode. It is not for a single field and changes in this hook would have no effect, when using the field alone, for example in a view. Using this hook would be the answer to the question *Which is the preferred way to change the display (view mode) of an entity, before it is rendered?*

(When using this hook, don't digg to deep, you can only change the render elements in the top level. Not the referenced objects, they are only to get information, not to change the rendering)

But the question is to change the rendering of a field, you asked *"everywhere throughout all contents"* For this the right solution is a field formatter, this can be used everywhere in drupal, whenever a field is rendered, no matter if you define a display mode (aka view mode) of an entity or use the field in Views.

To make the picture complete, you can change a field twice while displaying content, first in a field formatter and the second time, when the whole content is build and this build array can be altered in `hook_entity_view_alter()`

In drupal 8 field formatters are no longer hooks, they are now plugins.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/8

The documentation does not help to setup this plugin. I would copy an example from core and put my own code in it, for example:

```
core\modules\datetime\src\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter
```

Comment: Thanks for these informations. I will take time to examine all that before accepting one of the 2 answers! Meantime, I upvote each of them :) For my try with `hook_entity_view_alter()`, I agree but had found a way to browse all its internal to detect fields in it. Sure it's quite complex...

Comment: But you only have the fields that are configured in the view mode (default is "full", but it can be any view mode, that is going through this hook). And if you use it in Views, you have to use it as content, if you configure it as fields, then this hook has no effect.

Comment: Not had time yet to deeply examine it, but yes: I noticed it should be an uncertain way. It's why I said it's a complex approach. Thanks for pointing it more.

Comment: I think, you should consider `hook_entity_view_alter()` as the answer to the question: _Which is the preferred way to change the display (view mode) of an entity, before it is rendered?_

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand anymore. Maybe it's due to the fact that I'm not easy with English, but I seem you first discouraged me from, then now recommend me to use `hook_entity_view_alter()`. What I'd noticed when trying to work with it was tthat I should iterate deeply `$build` in order to localize all fields, then exploring them (having diferent structures) and yet targetting different sub-places in them such as `text` or `value`... so it seems no easy to be sure I could _in advance_ inventory all cases I would face.

Comment: I put the comments in the answer, I hope now it is clearer

Comment: Yes I think I clearly distinguish the options now. And you targetted the important thing for me, when pointing my "everywhere throughout all contents" condition. So from your precisions I will choose to use a formatter. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same in Drupal 8 as well. You can create a new formatter or can extend existing formatter. You need to create a field formatter plugin inside `src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter` directory.

```
/modules/random/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/RandomDefaultFormatter.php
```

You can created a formatter for specific fields type types based on Annotations :

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'Random_default' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "Random_default",
 *   label = @Translation("Random text"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "string"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

You can extend any existing formatter or extend `FormatterBase` class:

```
class RandomDefaultFormatter extends FormatterBase {
```

The method you may want to use :

```
FormatterInterface::viewElements()
```

**Related Links that can help :**

https://www.drupal.org/node/2620966

http://realize.be/drupal-8-field-api-series-part-1-field-formatters

Comment: Thanks for these informations. I will take time to examine all that before accepting one of the 2 answers! Meantime, I upvote each of them :)

Comment: @cFreed Please see my updated answer. :)